# Navigation inside modal using go_router

Tags: flutter

In general, go_router is used to navigate from one page to another page. The page that we navigated will show in front of the previous page. But how to implement this inside of showModalBottomSheet?

I have a modal that show only half screen. Then, when i click button where navigate to the new page, the page is show in front of the modal. But what i want is the new page still showing inside half modal.

Comment: Check ShellRoute https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/go_router/ShellRoute-class.html, basically you want an inner router with pages that can change and on top of that the outer router with the bottom sheet, so it will change the inner router with out modifying the bottom sheet or outer router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Copyright 2013 The Flutter Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MusicAppDemo());
}

class MusicAppDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  MusicAppDemo({super.key});

  final MusicDatabase database = MusicDatabase.mock();

  final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
    initialLocation: '/library',
    routes: <RouteBase>[
      ShellRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state, Widget child) {
          return MusicAppShell(
            currentIndex: switch (state.uri.path) {
              var p when p.startsWith('/recents') => 1,
              var p when p.startsWith('/search') => 2,
              _ => 0,
            },
            child: child,
          );
        },
        routes: <RouteBase>[
          GoRoute(
            path: '/library',
            pageBuilder: (context, state) {
              return FadeTransitionPage(
                child: const LibraryScreen(),
                key: state.pageKey,
              );
            },
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                path: 'album/:albumId',
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                  return AlbumScreen(
                    albumId: state.pathParameters['albumId'],
                  );
                },
                routes: [
                  GoRoute(
                    path: 'song/:songId',
                    // Display on the root Navigator
                    builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                      return SongScreen(
                        songId: state.pathParameters['songId']!,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          GoRoute(
            path: '/recents',
            pageBuilder: (context, state) {
              return FadeTransitionPage(
                child: const RecentlyPlayedScreen(),
                key: state.pageKey,
              );
            },
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                path: 'song/:songId',
                // Display on the root Navigator
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                  return SongScreen(
                    songId: state.pathParameters['songId']!,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          GoRoute(
            path: '/search',
            pageBuilder: (context, state) {
              final query = state.uri.queryParameters['q'] ?? '';
              return FadeTransitionPage(
                child: SearchScreen(
                  query: query,
                ),
                key: state.pageKey,
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      /// This one is outsise ShellRoute so it won't share any state
      GoRoute(
        path: '/settings',
        pageBuilder: (context, state) {
          return FadeTransitionPage(
            child: const SettingsScreen(),
            key: state.pageKey,
          );
        },
      ),
    ],
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Music app',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorSchemeSeed: Colors.pink,
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      routerConfig: _router,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return MusicDatabaseScope(
          state: database,
          child: child!,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class MusicAppShell extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final int currentIndex;

  const MusicAppShell({
    super.key,
    required this.child,
    required this.currentIndex,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: child,
      /// This button only purpose is open a bottomsheet so you can select and see that works the same as the NavigationBar, but with this your bottomSheet won't be disposed or closed
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          await showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            isScrollControlled: true,
            useRootNavigator: true,
            enableDrag: true,
            builder: (context) {
              return DraggableScrollableSheet(
                maxChildSize: 0.5,
                expand: false,
                initialChildSize: 0.25,
                builder: (context, scrollController) {
                  final theme = Theme.of(context);
                  return Material(
                    color: theme.scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                    shape: theme.bottomSheetTheme.shape,
                    clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                    child: ListView(
                      children: [
                        ListTile(
                          leading: const Icon(Icons.my_library_music_rounded),
                          title: const Text('Library'),
                          onTap: () => _onItemTapped(0, context),
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          leading: const Icon(Icons.timelapse),
                          title: const Text('Recently Played'),
                          onTap: () => _onItemTapped(1, context),
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          leading: const Icon(Icons.search),
                          title: const Text('Search'),
                          onTap: () => _onItemTapped(2, context),
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          leading: const Icon(Icons.settings),
                          title: const Text('Settings'),
                          onTap: () => _onItemTapped(3, context),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          );
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.more),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.my_library_music_rounded),
            label: 'Library',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.timelapse),
            label: 'Recently Played',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            label: 'Search',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        onTap: (int idx) => _onItemTapped(idx, context),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index, BuildContext context) {
    switch (index) {
      case 1:
        GoRouter.of(context).go('/recents');
        break;
      case 2:
        GoRouter.of(context).go('/search');
        break;
      case 3:
        GoRouter.of(context).go('/settings');
        break;
      case 0:
      default:
        GoRouter.of(context).go('/library');
        break;
    }
  }
}


/// Part of Dartpad's example but can be ignored
class LibraryScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const LibraryScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final database = MusicDatabase.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Library'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, albumId) {
          final album = database.albums[albumId];
          return AlbumTile(
            album: album,
            onTap: () {
              GoRouter.of(context).go('/library/album/$albumId');
            },
          );
        },
        itemCount: database.albums.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RecentlyPlayedScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const RecentlyPlayedScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final database = MusicDatabase.of(context);
    final songs = database.recentlyPlayed;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Recently Played'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final song = songs[index];
          final albumIdInt = int.tryParse(song.albumId)!;
          final album = database.albums[albumIdInt];
          return SongTile(
            album: album,
            song: song,
            onTap: () {
              GoRouter.of(context).go('/recents/song/${song.fullId}');
            },
          );
        },
        itemCount: songs.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String query;

  const SearchScreen({super.key, required this.query});

  @override
  State<SearchScreen> createState() => _SearchScreenState();
}

class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> {
  String? _currentQuery;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final database = MusicDatabase.of(context);
    final songs = database.search(widget.query);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Search'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Search...',
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
              onChanged: (String? newSearch) {
                _currentQuery = newSearch;
              },
              onEditingComplete: () {
                GoRouter.of(context).go(
                  '/search?q=$_currentQuery',
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final song = songs[index];
                return SongTile(
                  album: database.albums[int.tryParse(song.albumId)!],
                  song: song,
                  onTap: () {
                    GoRouter.of(context).go(
                        '/library/album/${song.albumId}/song/${song.fullId}');
                  },
                );
              },
              itemCount: songs.length,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AlbumScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? albumId;

  const AlbumScreen({
    required this.albumId,
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final database = MusicDatabase.of(context);
    final albumIdInt = int.tryParse(albumId ?? '');
    final album = database.albums[albumIdInt!];
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Album - ${album.title}'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 200,
                  height: 200,
                  child: Container(
                    color: album.color,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  ),
                ),
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      album.title,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      album.artist,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final song = album.songs[index];
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(song.title),
                    leading: SizedBox(
                      width: 50,
                      height: 50,
                      child: Container(
                        color: album.color,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      ),
                    ),
                    trailing: SongDuration(
                      duration: song.duration,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      GoRouter.of(context)
                          .go('/library/album/$albumId/song/${song.fullId}');
                    },
                  );
                },
                itemCount: album.songs.length,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SongScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String songId;

  const SongScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.songId,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final database = MusicDatabase.of(context);
    final song = database.getSongById(songId);
    final albumIdInt = int.tryParse(song.albumId);
    final album = database.albums[albumIdInt!];

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Song - ${song.title}'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
                child: Container(
                  color: album.color,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      song.title,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayMedium,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      album.title,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MusicDatabase {
  final List<Album> albums;
  final List<Song> recentlyPlayed;
  final Map<String, Song> _allSongs = {};

  MusicDatabase(this.albums, this.recentlyPlayed) {
    _populateAllSongs();
  }

  factory MusicDatabase.mock() {
    final albums = _mockAlbums().toList();
    final recentlyPlayed = _mockRecentlyPlayed(albums).toList();
    return MusicDatabase(albums, recentlyPlayed);
  }

  Song getSongById(String songId) {
    if (_allSongs.containsKey(songId)) {
      return _allSongs[songId]!;
    }
    throw ('No song with ID $songId found.');
  }

  List<Song> search(String searchString) {
    final songs = <Song>[];
    for (var song in _allSongs.values) {
      final album = albums[int.tryParse(song.albumId)!];
      if (song.title.contains(searchString) ||
          album.title.contains(searchString)) {
        songs.add(song);
      }
    }
    return songs;
  }

  void _populateAllSongs() {
    for (var album in albums) {
      for (var song in album.songs) {
        _allSongs[song.fullId] = song;
      }
    }
  }

  static MusicDatabase of(BuildContext context) {
    final routeStateScope =
        context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<MusicDatabaseScope>();
    if (routeStateScope == null) throw ('No RouteState in scope!');
    return routeStateScope.state;
  }

  static Iterable<Album> _mockAlbums() sync* {
    for (var i = 0; i < Colors.primaries.length; i++) {
      final color = Colors.primaries[i];
      final title = WordPair.random().toString();
      final artist = WordPair.random().toString();
      final songs = <Song>[];
      for (var j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
        final minutes = math.Random().nextInt(3) + 3;
        final seconds = math.Random().nextInt(60);
        final title = WordPair.random();
        final duration = Duration(minutes: minutes, seconds: seconds);
        final song = Song('$j', '$i', '$title', duration);

        songs.add(song);
      }
      yield Album('$i', title, artist, color, songs);
    }
  }

  static Iterable<Song> _mockRecentlyPlayed(List<Album> albums) sync* {
    for (var album in albums) {
      final songIndex = math.Random().nextInt(album.songs.length);
      yield album.songs[songIndex];
    }
  }
}

class MusicDatabaseScope extends InheritedWidget {
  final MusicDatabase state;

  const MusicDatabaseScope({
    required this.state,
    required super.child,
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(covariant InheritedWidget oldWidget) {
    return oldWidget is MusicDatabaseScope && state != oldWidget.state;
  }
}

class Album {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String artist;
  final Color color;
  final List<Song> songs;

  Album(this.id, this.title, this.artist, this.color, this.songs);
}

class Song {
  final String id;
  final String albumId;
  final String title;
  final Duration duration;

  Song(this.id, this.albumId, this.title, this.duration);

  String get fullId => '$albumId-$id';
}

class AlbumTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Album album;
  final VoidCallback? onTap;

  const AlbumTile({super.key, required this.album, this.onTap});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: SizedBox(
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        child: Container(
          color: album.color,
        ),
      ),
      title: Text(album.title),
      subtitle: Text(album.artist),
      onTap: onTap,
    );
  }
}

class SongTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Album album;
  final Song song;
  final VoidCallback? onTap;

  const SongTile(
      {super.key, required this.album, required this.song, this.onTap});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: SizedBox(
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        child: Container(
          color: album.color,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        ),
      ),
      title: Text(song.title),
      trailing: SongDuration(
        duration: song.duration,
      ),
      onTap: onTap,
    );
  }
}

class SongDuration extends StatelessWidget {
  final Duration duration;

  const SongDuration({
    required this.duration,
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
        '${duration.inMinutes.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(duration.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}');
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  const SettingsScreen({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      body: Center(
        child: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
          onPressed: () => GoRouter.of(context).go('/library'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// A page that fades in an out.
class FadeTransitionPage extends CustomTransitionPage<void> {
  /// Creates a [FadeTransitionPage].
  FadeTransitionPage({
    required super.key,
    required super.child,
  }) : super(
            transitionsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                    Animation<double> animation,
                    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
                    Widget child) =>
                FadeTransition(
                  opacity: animation.drive(_curveTween),
                  child: child,
                ));

  static final CurveTween _curveTween = CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeIn);
}
```

This code is from the GoRoute Dartpad example but modified so you can see how it works

[Gist](https://dartpad.dev/?id=6917ea415b16646942e9467abe6e1cf5)

The example shows straight forward how to use ShellRoute with a BottomNavigationBar, but I added a fab that opens a bottomsheet as your example, there you can select the same options and the background widget will change, except for the last one "settings", I created it outside of the shell route so you can see that using a route outside that will change the whole widget (disposing the bottomsheet)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The **go_router** package is a package used to facilitate page management in Flutter applications. The **showModalBottomSheet** function is used to open subpages. You can follow these steps to open two showModalBottomSheets, nested one after another.

```
 void main() {
   runApp(MyApp());
   }

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Nested Bottom Sheets'),
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // İlk bottom sheet'i aç
          showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.music_note),
                      title: Text('Music'),
                      onTap: () {
                        // İkinci bottom sheet'i aç
                        showModalBottomSheet(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return Container(
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  ListTile(
                                    leading: Icon(Icons.radio),
                                    title: Text('Radio'),
                                    onTap: () {
                                      // İkinci bottom sheet kapat
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  ListTile(
                                    leading: Icon(Icons.album),
                                    title: Text('Album'),
                                    onTap: () {
                                      // İkinci bottom sheet kapat
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.photo),
                      title: Text('Photos'),
                      onTap: () {
                        // İlk bottom sheet'i kapat
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
        child: Text('Open Bottom Sheet'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are delivering simple enough pages within the `ModalBottomSheet` then consider using a `boolean` value to control which page gets rendered. There is no need to spice things up.

Otherwise, if you have a sub-complex tree under your `ModalBottomSheet`, e.g >3 screens with layers of page. Try to define it explicitly as a new tree and assign it to `showModalBottomSheet's builder`, then it will be built using the modal's `context`, hence not trying to extend the whole screen size.